# How do I get the functions to divide?

Tags: python, function, math

```
import yfinance as yf 
import time
import math
import decimal
from decimal import *
T = yf.Ticker("T")
#the thing to get the annual percentage
def DivYield():
    div = T.info['dividendYield']
    d = Decimal(div)

    num_1 = d
    num_2 = 100
    M_percent = num_1 * num_2
    print(Decimal(int(round(M_percent, 2))))
#The annual percentage the stock will yield

#The last quoted price
def Last_price():
    tickers = ['T']
    for ticker in tickers:
        ticker_yahoo = yf.Ticker(ticker)
        data = ticker_yahoo.history()
        last_quote = data['Close'].iloc[-1]
        Prince = Decimal(last_quote)
        print(Decimal(int(round(Prince, 2))))

DivYield()
Last_price()

#price = (Last_price)
#DY = (DivYield)

payout = DivYield / Last_price

print(payout)
```

The "payout" is suppose to be the int from the DivYield and Last_Price divided with 2 decimal points(I believe the result is suppose to be about 3.48). However, when I run the code I receive,

```
`payout = DivYield / Last_price
         ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'function' and 'function'`

When printing just the functions I get the expected numbers so I'm confused why I am unable to divide the two.

I'm fairly new to programming and this site. I apologize if the way I posted this question or the code itself is hard to read/understand.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to use `return` instead of `print` for both of your functions.
Change `print(Decimal(int(round(M_percent, 2))))` to `return(Decimal(int(round(M_percent, 2))))`. Same for the other function. This comment `#price = (Last_price) #DY = (DivYield)` could work by price = `Last_price()` and `DY = DivYield()`. Calling these two functions will get the value from return then you can `payout = DY / price`.